# How to Send OCSP Request and receive OCSP response on Mobile Phone

Tags: mobile, java-me, digital-certificate, ocsp

I need to make comparison (on the basis of time) on OCSP request/response between a mobile device and desktop clients. I understand that one can use OpenSSL and other similar command line tools to check OCSP on desktop clients. But I don’t know how to go about making OCSP request on a mobile phone. 
I want to send OCSP request for known certificate (e.g Facebook's) to its OSCP URL (http://ocsp.digicert.com) and obtain the certificate's revocation status.
Is there any tool or a guide on sample code (preferably J2ME) that I can use to send OCSP request and get response?
I understand that the BouncyCastle library for mobile devices has some sample classes related to OCSP. I have gone through but I have not been able to make much sense from them.

Answer (score 0):

You could base64 the OCSP request and send it across on HTTP to the OCSP URL and then time it. Note that there might be a CDN that would serve the OCSP Response and that would factor in with the latency as well by reducing it. 
How do you create an OCSP Request: 
http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=42

Comment: @ Khanna111GauravKhanr. Thanks for your response. However, the link you provided uses openSSL. My little search on openSSL suggests that it can not be used on mobile phones (like Nokia Asha 502). i am looking for j2ME (or Android) code through which i can send OCSP request containing, a leaf certificate to be validated,its root certificate, etc, all sent to the cert's OCSP server URL. and how to receive the server's response

Comment: You need to use openssl to construct the http request and then use that on the mobile phone and perhaps use a timer API to time it. I am talking about OCSP request on HTTP GET.

Comment: OpenSSL can be used on the desktop to construct the OCSP HTTP GET Request

Comment: thanks once again. I can currently use OpenSSL to construct ocsp request and get response on my desktop machine. my problem is; how can i do that on a mobile phone? or are you saying openssl can work on mobile phone? if yes, please tell me more; is it OS-specific, i mean on android, symbian, etc ...Please tell me more about how to go about that

Comment: No that is not what I am saying. you can construct an ocsp request and then use it to invoke the http url: http://ocsp.XXX.com/OCSP_REQ on the mobile and time it. uy

Comment: Once you have the ocsp request from the desktop, on the mobile you can use http (browser) to invoke the OCSP server as in http://ocsp.xxx.com/OCSPREQ and use a timer API. Or you could write a mobile program that does it all including creating the ocsp request.

Comment: @ Khanna111GauravKhanr. Thanks so much. I now understand what you mean. I will try just that and hopefully get back to you soon. thanks once again.

Comment: I am still having issues generating the OSCP request. I have used BC’s OSCP Request class available in the lightweight package. but i am getting a nullpointerException error. i think it has to do with programing the class to pick the necessary parameters like serialNumber, issuerName and keyhash values from a stored certificate. i have added the certificate to the "src" folder of the application. please any assistance in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try "openssl ocsp" command to create the request. I believe an example is in the link that was referred to earlier. Do not have a sample using bouncy castle as of now. I will see if I can get one for you.